# Apple Push Notification service in background in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I am trying to add push notifications to my apps. Everything is working fine (I receive the messages) but I can't get the script to work in the background. I want to have push.php running in the background 24/7 to send the messages automatically. I have managed to get it into the background (it shows up in cPanel's process manager without me having it open), but nothing actually happens. I never receive the push that push.php sends to my device. If I visit push.php manually though, I receive the push withen a few seconds.

I have tried:

```
passthru("/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/push.php >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1 &");
```

log.log contains: "Content-type: text/html" printed over and over.

```
exec ("nohup /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/push.php >/path/to/log.log &");
```

log.log contains: "Content-type: text/html" printed once.

```
exec("nohup php /path/to/push.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null&");
```

All of them show up in cPanel process's, however none of them actually send to push to my device. Also, sometimes push.php shows up in cPanel multiple times. As I said above, if I visit push.php manually, I get the push.

Comment: Shared hosting may terminate longish running processes. You'd probably need to get a VPS or dedicated server (or use something like AWS or Heroku)

Comment: @jli I had a live chat with HostGator yesterday where I asked them if I could have a PHP loop running in the background 24/7. They told me it is fine.

Comment: Maybe ask them for their preferred method of doing so then?